# What will be size of UiView for drawing pdf File for A4 size paper?

Tags: iphone, ios5, cocos2d-iphone, pdf-generation, ios6

Could anyone help me out what would be the size of UIView For Drawing pdf for A4 size paper.

I am using the below size but my pdfView objects like labels, images not in the size that I provide for drawing.

I create .xib and draw manually UILabels, Images, and lines Then using tag property I am provide frame for drawing but they draw different location according to .xib I am providing same size that I have in .xib (0, 0, 792, 1122).

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 792, 1122), nil);

+(void)drawLabels:(NSMutableArray*)arr isData:(BOOL)isdata
{

    NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PDFView" owner:nil options:nil];

    UIView* mainView = [objects objectAtIndex:0];


    if (isdata) 
    {
        for (int i=1;i<=[arr count];i++)
        {
            UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)[mainView viewWithTag:i];
            [self drawText:[arr objectAtIndex:i-1] inFrame:lbl.frame isData:isdata];
        }
    }
}
```

**//Here is my Draw Method**

```
+(void)drawText:(NSString*)textToDraw inFrame:(CGRect)frameRect isData:(BOOL)isdata
{
    int length=[textToDraw length];
    CFStringRef string = (__bridge CFStringRef) textToDraw; 
    CFMutableAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0); 
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Helvetica Neue Bold", 12.0f, nil);
    if (isdata) 
    {
        font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Helvetica Neue ", 12.0f, nil);
    }
    CFAttributedStringReplaceString (currentText,CFRangeMake(0, 0), string);
    CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(currentText,CFRangeMake(0, length),kCTFontAttributeName,font);
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);
    CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);
    CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
    CGPathRelease(framePath);
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2);
    CFRelease(frameRef);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
}
```

**// For Line Drawing I am using Below Code**

```
for (int j=1001;j<=1003;j++)
        {
            UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)[mainView viewWithTag:j];

            CGPoint lblPoint=CGPointMake(lbl.frame.origin.x, lbl.frame.origin.y);
            CGPoint lblPoint2=CGPointMake(lbl.frame.origin.x+lbl.frame.size.width, lbl.frame.origin.y);
            [self drawLineFromPoint:lblPoint toPoint:lblPoint2];
        }

+(void)drawLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)from toPoint:(CGPoint)to
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat components[] = {0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4};
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, from.x, from.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, to.x, to.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGColorRelease(color);
}
```

**Here is My .xib**
[image]

**Here is my .pdf File after Drawing**

[image]

Comment: A4 paper size is 595 x 842 points, not 792 x 1122.

Comment: Are all labels direct subviews of `mainView`?

Comment: Martin could you please help if possible in this regards?

Comment: Martin its very urgent to implement this functionality, how can provide bounty or some thing that it can be easily answer or be active.

Comment: Why is there a factor `* 2` in `CGContextTranslateCTM()`? - I can try to help further, but not before this evening (German time).

Comment: Actually I don't know about much more I am just following http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2 tutorial. Okay No Prob when you are free you can look at this issue thanks a lot.

Comment: I think I have found an error in the sample code from that link. Please check my answer below and tell me if it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If have downloaded the project from http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2, and it seems that the CTM calculations in the `drawText:` method can be improved. The problem is that the height of the rect is not taken into account when modifying the transformation matrix.

If you replace

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2);
...
CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2);
```

with

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2 + frameRect.size.height);
...
CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2 - frameRect.size.height);
```

then the result seems to be more accurate.

Also the Xcode static analyzer reports a memory leak of `currentText` in that method, so you should add

```
CFRelease(currentText);
```

add the end of `drawText:`.

Comment: Thanks for your time but Martin it just drawing revert ,the screen logo just below and text  also in revert(reflect form) and somewhere correct. When I comment CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2..... Then it draws labels but not what size i provide some are on first page some on second ......

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman: Have you replaced *both* instances of `CGContextTranslateCTM`? I have tested it with the Ray Wenderlich sample project, and the result seemed to be good. - It is a bit difficult to see where the problem in your project is without having the source code. *If you want* you can make a reduced project that shows your problem and put it somewhere where I can download it. I will have a look at it.

Comment: Martin my skype id is: pandey.ios please add me

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman: I am not using Skype. Can you put it in a Dropbox folder and publish the link?

Comment: Yes I can how to put in dropbox folder

Comment: Martin i Think chat session has ended many time i tried to reload but session not start over

Comment: Okay Thanks for your efforts Mr. Martin, I will be online approx. up to next 6 hours. Today I have to submitted demo for client. my boss also chasing me.

Comment: Ok Mr. Martin I will try to resolve this issue By the Way a lot of thanks for your efforts and my wish to have a great time:)

Comment: Martin where should i send you the source code files for pdf creation plz tell me. if you can help me plz tell me I do needful. Thanks

Comment: I have sent the files get them.

Comment: Yes it has I can see in sent mail BTW I have forwarded it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17379/discussion-between-pandey-laxman-and-martin-r)

Comment: Could you plz suggest me other way?

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman: Go to http://uploaded.net, upload the ZIP file. You will get a link that you can post here.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
NSArray *aArrPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;

NSString *aStrPrintPdfPath = [[aArrPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDocument.pdf"];
CGContextRef aCgPDFContextRef = [self createPDFContext:CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 892) path:(__bridge_retained CFStringRef)aStrPrintPdfPath];

CGContextBeginPage(aCgPDFContextRef,nil);
  //turn PDF upsidedown
    CGAffineTransform aCgAffTrans = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    aCgAffTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,892);
    aCgAffTrans = CGAffineTransformScale(aCgAffTrans, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(aCgPDFContextRef, aCgAffTrans);

//capture whole view screenshot
[self.view.layer renderInContext:aCgPDFContextRef]; //add QuartzCore framework and import it
    [aPageNote release]; 
    CGContextEndPage (aCgPDFContextRef);

CGContextRelease (aCgPDFContextRef);
NSLog(@"Pdf Successfully Created");
```

Also add this method:

```
-(CGContextRef) createPDFContext:(CGRect)aCgRectinMediaBox path:(CFStringRef) aCfStrPath
{

  CGContextRef aCgContextRefNewPDF = NULL;
  CFURLRef aCfurlRefPDF;
  aCfurlRefPDF = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL,aCfStrPath,kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle,false);
  if (aCfurlRefPDF != NULL) {
    aCgContextRefNewPDF = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL (aCfurlRefPDF,&aCgRectinMediaBox,NULL);
    CFRelease(aCfurlRefPDF); 
  }
  return aCgContextRefNewPDF;
}
```

Comment: But I have a lot of data so I need to create pdf for multiple pages.In this view I need to add table cell and repeat it in newt pages of pdf. Pdf should be searchable some time ago I try to create it using making screen shots and scrolling uitable view internally but my senior rejected there was no search and selection of text.